# Why some variables' coefficients are negative in linear regression?

Tags: r, regression

I have 2 models and 5 variables in my multiple linear regression analysis. In Model 1, it consists of all of the variables, but some of them have negative t values. If I remove one of the negative coefficients and build the 2nd model with 4 variables, all of them are positive. What might be the problem with my 1st Model?

Comment: No problem. It just means some confounding is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the fact that you describe depends from correlations among regressors. If you change regressors list the changes in parameters values are usual. The fact the one or more coefficients change their sign depends on particular correlations structure. To check the correlation matrix can help you. Only in the particular case where regressors are orthogonal, as in PCA case, the coefficients remain unchanged.